# Outlook add-in on Outlook for Mac: clear cache?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

In Outlook for Mac, an office.js Outlook add-in runs in a task pane that I assume is a Safari web control. I have not been able to determine how you clear the cached files from an add-in running in the task pane.

Does anyone know how to manually clear the task pane's browser cache? I cannot find an official answer, just guesses.

Thanks.

Comment: It is an embedded WebKit instance. That said, what is the issue that you are running into?

Comment: During testing we sometimes need to ensure that the new code is being loaded, but are getting the older cached files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the documentation contains the information you're looking for:  [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest#clear-the-office-cache)

> For Mac:
>
> Delete the contents of the folder:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Containers/com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost/Data/
> ```

Comment: The first time I clear this directory, it worked. However, the second time I wanted to clear cache, this directory is empty...So how can I clear cache?

Comment: That folder (com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost) doesn’t exist on my computer. There is a com.microsoft.Outlook, hmm don’t feel great deleting the Data folder there, but I guess I’ll try moving it.

Answer (score 4):

Outlook has changed cache path, the new one is `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Caches`

Comment: In addition to this, cookies can be cleared by deleting `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies` 

Here's a command:
```rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Outlook```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when building a custom function. My js was being cached and was not reloaded when pushed updated code to my webserver.

To remove the cache on my mac I deleted the contents of the following directory:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Caches/
```